# Android alarm clock app crashes SystemUI with NullPointerException under Oreo (only)

Tags: android

I have an Android alarm clock app. I have the usual(?) alarm Intent -> receiver -> activity chain, whose last step creates a full-screen window and sounds the alarm.

All this works fine on pre-Oreo (API 26) versions of Android. But on Oreo, when the alarm fires, the System UI crashes and I get this exception in the emulator (slightly reformatted here):

```
        12-12 01:15:02.864 9570-9570/com.android.systemui E/AndroidRuntime: 
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.android.systemui, PID: 9570
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.NavigationBarFragment.onKeyguardOccludedChanged(boolean)' on a null object reference
at com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.StatusBar.onKeyguardOccludedChanged(StatusBar.java:3843)
at com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.StatusBarKeyguardViewManager.setOccluded(StatusBarKeyguardViewManager.java:277)
at com.android.systemui.keyguard.KeyguardViewMediator.handleSetOccluded(KeyguardViewMediator.java:1176)
at com.android.systemui.keyguard.KeyguardViewMediator.-wrap14(Unknown Source:0)
at com.android.systemui.keyguard.KeyguardViewMediator$4.handleMessage(KeyguardViewMediator.java:1531)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

As a possible clue, I've found that when I remove `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED` from `win.addFlags()`, it doesn't crash -- but of course, it also doesn't show the alarm when the phone is locked.

I don't remember everything I've tried, but here are some of the things:

1. Locating Android's `StatusBar.java` source code to try to figure out exactly what thing is null that's not supposed to be. My Google-fu has failed me here, apparently.
2. Explicitly dismissing the keyguard with something like `getSystemService(KeyguardManager.class).requestDismissKeyguard(this, null);`.
3. Dismissing the keyguard by using `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD`.
4. Both explicitly showing and explicitly hiding the status bar.
5. I think I tried some other method of showing the window when locked -- like, calling `setShowWhenLocked(true)` or something like that. But it didn't help, and anyway that method was added only in API 27, so it wouldn't solve the problem for API 26 even if it *had* worked.
6. Um ... other things I no longer remember.

None of these has had any effect.

Clearly this *can* work, because other alarm clock apps work under Oreo. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've since downloaded the Android source repo and have a better understanding of why this is happening, but still no idea what to do about it. I observe that the `StatusBar.java` code that NPEs at this line doesn't have a null check for `mNavigationBar`, as there is almost everywhere else, but I'm loath to just consider this an Android bug -- it's much more likely that my ignorance is at fault. (And anyway, even if it _were_ an Android bug, there's surely some workaround!)

Comment: Adding to the list of things I've tried: explicitly hiding _both_ the status bar and the navigation bar, per https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html.

Comment: is this verified as ignorable? I've got the same thing on some device emulations, but not on others... would suck to release and find out it was not simply an emulator issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Known bug that has been fixed it seems. Especially on the emulator.
So update the image used in the emulator.

It was present in the original Oreo release it seems according to the history if I interpret it correctly. Fixed in 8.0.0_r21 and later, present in 8.0.0_r17 and earlier and can't see any between those).

What exact versions of Oreo, have you tried 8.1 and/or various patch levels?
Because it's was fixed Sep 20 according to this commit, maybe another commit as well:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/8078996f4a8b1718a2ca56ff52fd1f4d522e7720%5E1..8078996f4a8b1718a2ca56ff52fd1f4d522e7720/

Possibly:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/9c4faa85f1bc4ffc2aa949da7b5d8439f4c638a2

Or their related source commit (noticed it was merge commits).
I quote one of them:

> Fix random systemui crashes during boot
>
> When trying to boot android in emulator, systemui may crash due to an
>   uninitialized value of mNavigationBar probably because of some race
>   condition during initialization caused by emulation performance issues

Comment: Hot damn. Odd, because the source branch I checked out was r35 and it _does_ have this bug -- and I updated the emulator not too long ago (certainly well after Sep 20). But I'll try updating again tonight. In any case, it sounds like I can just ignore this. Thanks so much for the answer!

Comment: Well Sep 20 was one of the merges of it, will be quite some time until it appears in a released image.

Comment: is this verified as ignorable?  I've got the same thing on some device emulations, but not on others...  would suck to release and find out it was not simply an emulator issue.

Comment: @MattiasIsegranBergander I don't see 8.0.0_r17 or _r21 on the sdkmanager system image updates (it only has _r12), and couldn't find any sort of AOSP nightly builds. Are you building your own? I'm concerned I need Play services, and won't be able to compile them.