# Getting System UI errors when alarm clock alarms after Oreo upgrade

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I have seen a few articles talking about System UI errors dealing with the built in alarm clock, but none seem to have any answers.  I was just recently forced upgraded to Oreo (8.0.0) on a SAMSUNG-SM-G930A on AT&T.  The alarm seems to go off fine, but after hitting the snooze a few times, I start getting System UI errors.  Then I seem to have some flakiness, slowness, and battery draining until I reboot.

I have also tried resetting all of my app settings to attempt to fix this.

The closest article I can find is this one:

[Android alarm clock app crashes SystemUI with NullPointerException under Oreo (only)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47915026/android-alarm-clock-app-crashes-systemui-with-nullpointerexception-under-oreo-o/48084299#48084299)

Unless someone knows of a way to try 8.1 without jail breaking?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://medium.com/@benexus/background-services-in-android-o-862121d96c95

Comment: Not sure how this helps.  This is from the built in clock app.  Also, I have now seen this error when someone calls me and it shows the screen for the incoming call.  Smells like someone did not do a good job testing before this roll out.